# Using the Filter Type UpdatedAt with Marketo Activity Bulk Extract API

Tags: marketo, matillion, cdata-drivers

We are trying to use the Marketo Activity Bulk Extract API to get Activities within a certain date range. However, there doesn't seem to be a high watermark (updatedAt, lastModifiedDate etc) filter available for this API.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

According to the Marketo [Bulk Activity Extract](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-activity-extract/) REST API reference, the low- and high-watermark points are determined by a mandatory filter on createdAt.

In the [Matillion Marketo](https://matillion-docs.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/datamodels/Marketo.html#RSBMarketo_p_UseBulkAPI.htm) reference documentation it's described as a filter on ActivityDate range, which must be specified when exporting bulk Activities data.

Comment: Does this mean, that the Activity records are immutable? Since there is no UpdateAt field to capture the modifications / updates to the record?

Comment: I think that updates to the lead would trigger the creation of a _new_ Data Value Change activity record, rather than go back and update historical data

Comment: @SaqibAli: Activity records themselves in Marketo are static and more akin to logs than say, Salesforce activities. They cannot be modified after being created.