# Marketo High Watermark and Field Definition Metadata Missing From API

Tags: marketo, matillion

Marketo Activity object API's missing High Watermark / Audit Fields. What is the potential way to identify changed records using UpdatedAt or ModifedDate like columns. None of the Activity Objects having this Audit column. What is best possible way to identify delta considering API limits

Also Is there any specific Object in Marketo for Field Metadata, which can be retrieved dynamically based on each Object filter to make the orchestration Dynamic. Basically looking for a system table in marketo which can be used as a data source and each Marketo object can be passed from Grid Variable to store the Field names in to a separate grid variable to use later

Did anyone face this kind of scenario before? Please share your experiences

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006800), according to the Marketo [Bulk Activity Extract](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-activity-extract) REST API reference, the low- and high-watermark points are determined by a mandatory filter on createdAt. There is no concept of updating Activity records.

Regarding field metadata, you maybe need [Custom Activities](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/administration/marketo-custom-activities/understanding-custom-activities.html?lang=en) or [Custom Objects](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/administration/marketo-custom-objects/understanding-marketo-custom-objects.html?lang=en)? The API describes a [Get Custom Activity Types](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/endpoint-index/) endpoint which I think is the system table you are looking for.

Comment: CreatedAt Filter is not appearing in API response so no valid way to put a filter on that. If there is no concept of updating Activity records, does this mean Activity records are always immutable?

Comment: Get Custom Activity Types are types of activity , not the metadata of each exposed object so won't be of much help in that regard